# Change the connected Azure Key Vault via an Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

We currently use Azure Key vault to store certain secrets, however now we are going into live we need to be able to use Azure Pipelines to change the connected key vault. I'm unable to determine a neat way of doing this through a pipeline, does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Change the connected Azure Key Vault via an Azure Pipeline

You could use the Az CLI to update the  with Azure CLI task by the command:

[Update-AzKeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/update-azkeyvault?view=azps-5.9.0):

```
Update-AzKeyVault
      -ResourceGroupName <String>
      -VaultName <String>
      [-EnablePurgeProtection]
      [-EnableRbacAuthorization <Boolean>]
      [-Tag <Hashtable>]
      [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

[image]

Or you could use the Set-AzKeyVaultSecret Az powershell cmdlet to create and update a secret in a key vault:

```
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName {keyVaultName} -Name 'MyAdminPassword' -SecretValue (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssword!2' -AsPlainText -Force)
```